# How to know if there is a formula to find an answer?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm working on a problem and I've found all the values to make it work and I'm trying to figure out if there's a formula in there I can use.

Here is what I have written out so far.

```
font size in pixels at (line height percent / 100) and x margin = correct character position
```

Here are values that I found by trial and error that work:

```
64px at 1.2 and -14px margin = correct character position
```

If I use a margin percent these values work:

```
12px at 1.2 and -0.18% = correct character position
24px at 1.2 and -0.60% = correct character position
36px at 1.2 and -1.12% = correct character position
64px at 1.2 and -2.00% = correct character position
```

Is there a formula I can get from that information?

Related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34983672/is-there-a-way-to-adjust-the-top-edge-of-characters-in-html-text-similar-to-flas) if you're interested.

You can test the values [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gLQU/19/). In the CSS panel find the text, "margin-top", enter a new value and click the run button in the upper left hand corner.

Concrete example:

[image]

Comment: You always can get a formula that meets this four couples. Your real question if it will predict properly the next values. I wonder if you got the values right - it seems that the first value is out of order. Is it a positive percentage?

Comment: Yes. You can enter the values here, http://jsfiddle.net/6gLQU/19/  and see the results. I've added more details above. Also, I've changed the values a bit to .18 and 1.12 and it still looks correct. I don't know if this makes it easier to predict the next values or not.